# Wine-staging fails to install on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wine, dependencies

I'm trying to run games through Lutris and followed [their wiki](https://github.com/lutris/lutris/wiki/Wine-Dependencies) on installing wine-staging.

When running:

```
$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

I get the error they predict, but then when running:

```
$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging wine-staging wine-staging-i386
```

I still have the unmet dependencies error (output below).

Could anyone direct me to a solution?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-staging : Depends: wine-staging-amd64 (= 4.13~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
 wine-staging-i386:i386 : Depends: libfaudio0:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libcairo2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: libcapi20-3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: libcups2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: libglu1-mesa:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                      libglu1:i386
                          Recommends: libgsm1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: libgtk-3-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: libkrb5-3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: libodbc1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: libosmesa6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: libpcap0.8:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: libsane:i386 or
                                  libsane1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: libv4l-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: libva-drm2:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                      libva-drm1:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libva-x11-2:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                      libva-x11-1:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libva2:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                      libva1:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libxcomposite1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: libxslt1.1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: This question is not really a duplicate, as it is wine specific. `libfaudio0` is missing in ubuntu repositories. To add it run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport` and then `sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging` to install winehq

Comment: @white The question is reopened, you may add your alternative solution as another answer now.

Answer (score 23):

I followed the instructions found [here](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=32192) to download the missing `libfaudio:i386`.

> Ubuntu 18.04:
>
> ```
> wget https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key
>
> sudo apt-key add Release.key
> ```
>
> Add the repository:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/ ./'
> ```
>
> Then update:
>
> ```
> sudo apt update
> ```

Comment: I tried using the repos in the other answers (the ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport repo) and it horribly broke things.  It wouldn't install because it conflicted with libfaudio (vs. libfaudio0), and no amount of shuffling helped.  While I didn't add the repo above directly, I did download the libfaudio i386 and amd64 manually, and then wine-staging finally installed correctly!

Answer (score 15):

I had similar problem, I went down a few different rabbit-holes so thought it might help others if I detail my solution. I am not particularly au fait with the apt packaging process or wine so I will list out everything that I went through from upgrading from wine3.0 to wine5.0 on ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

1. Purge all from APT!

> ```
> sudo apt-get purge *wine*
> ```

2. Check that there's no snaps installed too (for some reason i had this - not sure if it would impact so i assumed best to remove)

> ```
> sudo snap remove wine
> sudo snap update wine-platform-*
> ```

3. Remove the PPA official repos (they changed how they packaged this). We need to dig inside /etc/apt

> ```
> grep -Ril "wine" /etc/apt
> ```

If you get any matches comment them out or delete the keys, we will fully re-add later.

4. Enable 32-bit & add new repo (check [here](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) for other ubuntu versions)

> ```
> sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
> wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
> sudo apt-key add winehq.key
> sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt upgrade
> sudo apt --fix-broken install
> sudo apt autoremove --purge
> sudo apt upgrade
> ```

5. Let's get the libfaudio & libasound2 which are the broken repos:

> ```
> wget https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key
> sudo apt-key add Release.key
> sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/ ./'
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt install libfaudio0 libasound2-plugins:i386 -y
> ```

6. Now we can install wine 5.0 as normal!

> ```
> sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable -y
> ```

Comment: While attempting to set up Wine for Lutris per [this](https://github.com/lutris/lutris/wiki/Wine-Dependencies) page, I kept running into unmet dependency issues, despite their solution for that exact issue. Your answer actually resolved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Just step 5 and 6 was enough to fix the issue for me

Comment: For me, all unmet dependencies trace back to `libpulse0:i386`; this prevents installing the packages in the last line in your step 5. Any ideas?

Comment: only step 5 is needed

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by @chilly-chease, `libfaudio0:i386` package is missing in ubuntu 18.04 repositories.

The most simple way to fix it would be:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport`
2. `sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging`

Comment: I have no idea why you were downvoted. Apart from the missing `sudo apt-get update` which is required between 1 and 2 this should work.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I still complains about:  `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-staging-i386:i386 : Depends: libfaudio0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libpulse0:i386 (>= 0.99.1) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: @danger89 Same here on ubuntu 18.04. The fix: removed `ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport`, reinstalled the default ubuntu versions of the files modified by the above repo; downloaded and installed the `libfaudio0` amd64 and i386 libs from the above opensuse links; problem solved, I was able to install wine 5. I 'think' I read somewhere that `ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport` is no longer up to date for bionic?? You can try the `sudo apt-add-repository` way of installing `libfaudio0` as suggested in Chilly Cheese's answer, I didn't try.

Comment: Yup indeed. Opensuse repo does work. I have wine v5 correctly installed.

Comment: missing sudo apt-get update after adding the repo

Answer (score 0):

When you first executed:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

You left your package manager in a broken state and you need to remove all wine related packages first and get a working package state:

```
sudo apt remove winehq-staging wine\*
sudo apt install -f
```

Once you have your package manager in a working state you can try the workaround command of avoiding installing some recommended packages.

Comment: remove: `E: Unable to locate package winehq.key`

Comment: It does seem to work if I replace `wine-staging` with `wine-stable`, but I figure staging is better for running games

Comment: You are running the wrong commands and trying to pass a file as a package nane

Comment: Always quote `'wine*'` or escape `wine\*` package globs - otherwise they will be expanded by the shell as file globs, if you have any matching files in your current directory. That's likely what happened in @OdedSayar 's case. I'm editing your command.